Systems of partial differential equations and multiple hypergeometric functions
The following differential equation system show up in my research (it is related to the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$):
$$x_1(1-x_1)\partial_1^2f+x_2(1-x_2)\partial_2^2f+(x_1+x_2+x_3-2 x_1 x_2 -1)\partial_1 \partial_2f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_1\right)\partial_1f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_2\right)\partial_2f+\alpha_3f=0,$$
$$x_2(1-x_2)\partial_2^2f+x_3(1-x_3)\partial_3^2f+(x_1+x_2+x_3-2 x_2 x_3 -1)\partial_2 \partial_3f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_3\right)\partial_3f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_2\right)\partial_2f+\alpha_1f=0,$$
$$x_1(1-x_1)\partial_1^2f+x_3(1-x_3)\partial_3^2f+(x_1+x_2+x_3-2 x_1 x_3 -1)\partial_1 \partial_3f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_1\right)\partial_1f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_3\right)\partial_3f+\alpha_2f=0.$$
After taking proper linear combinations of the three differential equations, one get:
$$ x_1(1-x_1)\partial_1^2 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_3\right)\partial_1 \partial_3 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_2\right)\partial_1 \partial_2 f-\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_2 x_3\right)\partial_2 \partial_3 f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_1\right)\partial_1 f+\frac{\alpha_2+\alpha_3-\alpha_1}{2}f=0,$$
$$ x_2(1-x_2)\partial_2^2 f-\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_3\right)\partial_1 \partial_3 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_2\right)\partial_1 \partial_2 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_2 x_3\right)\partial_2 \partial_3 f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_2\right)\partial_2 f+\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_3-\alpha_2}{2}f=0,$$
$$ x_3(1-x_3)\partial_3^2 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_3\right)\partial_1 \partial_3 f-\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_1 x_2\right)\partial_1 \partial_2 f+\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)-1}{2}-x_2 x_3\right)\partial_2 \partial_3 f+\left(\frac{3}{2}-3 x_3\right)\partial_3 f+\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3}{2}f=0.$$
Now apart from the "off diagonal" second order derivative terms $\partial_i \partial_j f$, $i\neq j$, this set of differential equations look very much like the ones satisfied by the four Lauricella functions of three variables (see the attached picture. The book in the picture is Exton's Multiple hypergeometric functions and applications.) I've tried several coordinate transformations but I can't seem to reduce the equations above to the standard form. Does anyone recognize this set of differential equations? I am tempted to try and construct series solutions near $x_i=0$ by working out the recursion relation of the series coefficients. But it would be helpful to relate the solutions to known functions/series. Any advice on studying this type of PDE system would be appreciated. Thanks!
